# Connect BH40 headphone and bluetooth dongle

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, bluetooth

So I bought this [BT Dongle](https://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B0013BFQUE/ref=cm_cr_dp_see_all_summary?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=helpful), and this [headphone](http://www.acme.eu/en-us/products/bluetooth-devices/acme-bh40-foldable-bluetooth-headset), and I can't connect them on my PC (Win7 x64 Ultimate). I see the BT icon on the tray, I could also add the headphone through:

1. click BT icon on tray
2. Add device

It finds my headphone, and says, the device was added succesfully, but an "Installing drivers" window also prompts, shows 3 drivers and does not succeed with them.

I tried the solution written on the BT Dongle's site: change "Bluetooth Radio" to "Bluetooth Adapter" in device manager.

> - Right click "Generic Bluetooth Radio"
> - Select "Update driver software"
> - Select "Browse for driver software on my computer"
> - Select "Let me pick from list of device drivers on my computer"
> - Now "Generic Bluetooth Adapter" should be on the list, select it and click 'Next'
> - Correct driver will now install, may need to restart computer for changes to take effect.

And it works on my girlfriend's PC (Win 10 x64 Education), but not on mine, there is no headphone in the audio devices.

Answer (score 0):

According to several reviews for that USB Bluetooth dongle on Amazon, it doesn't work with Windows 7 (but could work with Windows 10 and others), which explains why it works on one computer but not the other.

I recommend just buying a new Bluetooth dongle made by a different company; they're fairly cheap.

Also keep in mind:

- When you used the second computer, did you use the same USB Bluetooth dongle and headphones? If so, the problem is probably with the first computer (probably your Operating System, Windows 7).
- Have you tried connecting any other Bluetooth Device to your computer using the same USB dongle (eg. keyboard, mouse, speakers)? If they work then it's probably the headphones, but if they have the same problem then it could be the dongle. It could also still be the OS or drivers, but the dongle is easier to test, and those Amazon reviews suggest that it is mostly likely the dongle combined with Windows 7.